# Database level lock in Microsoft SQL Server : schema migrations

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a distributed application with multiple processes on multiple servers connect to a SQL Server database.

I need to migrate the database schema in code during first startup, because upgrade deployment can be done with the user without database access (we use computer object database access).

Currently this is done by providing a sql file with statements and then a user with db access (but potentially without app access) would run this independently.

Because apps do not talk to each other (firewalls, different DCs etc.) I was thinking that i'd have to designate one server as 'master', all others as 'slaves' and then on the master the first process that'd start would obtain the mutex and do the schema migrations; all others could simply wait until they can see the schema is migrated.

However, this has a certain code smell to me.

I tried researching how Entity Framework handles this in code first migrations and seems they don't (e.g. if two processes start at exact same time they would both try to migrate schema).

Any other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You can change mode of database to single-user (other connections) will be refused. Make the changes and then change back multi-user mode.

**EDIT:**

There is trick, how to get "mutex". You can update/delete record(s). Until transaction is open, the exclusive lock is stil holded. Probably, if you delete 0 records (with table-lock hint) from every table in transaction, you probably achieve same behaviour as "global mutex" for the users of database. But I don't know what behaviour will be with schema changes.

Comment: This only works if there is no transaction log shipping; replicated db fails to enter SUM.